# Is it possible to create an offline application with Wicket?

Tags: java, wicket, offline

Is there a way to make an offline application using Wicket? If so, would it be necessary to use another tool/framework (Gears, Spring, etc)?

Comment: It's definitely not necessary to use another framework with Wicket. Although I might be misunderstanding that bit.

Comment: @biziclop As wicket does not solve the problem directly is necessary to use auxiliary tools. It may be that the only alternative is to replicate some of the commands from the server using javascript. I'll check out the alternatives mentioned.

Comment: I see, so you need these frameworks for your specific problem. I told you I might be misunderstanding the question and indeed I was :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe. Of course, you can use Wicket to generate HTML and JavaScript that executes on the client only without ever talking to a server.

So you can use any technology that you like but you must write the HTML in such a way that it never sends requests. That means for example: All links and forms must be handled by JavaScript functions.

Comment: @aaron-digulla Thanks. There is no way to escape. Then in this case I have to make custom javascript. :)

Comment: You can try GWT instead. GWT creates JavaScript from your Java code and using a server is optional. Or have a look at anything that supports HTML5 which is great for offline apps that run in the browser; look at the Chrome Store or Mozilla Apps (https://apps.mozillalabs.com/)

Comment: @aaron-digulla Good idea, may be possible to make browser plugins to solve the problem. Another alternative! :)

Answer (score 3):

Wicket is a **server-side** technology, just like servlets, jsp, etc; meaning that it generally requires an application-server to host the application. There's no offline equivalent that I'm aware of.

Spring can be also be run on an application server or be used to construct desktop applications. Perhaps you'll consider a desktop application to be offline?

Comment: @johan-sjoberg It's a web application. If the connection is off the user continue to use normally, but only to execute simple operations.

Comment: Wicket nor spring is written for that. You should look into `javascript`, `air`, `flash`, `silverlight`, etc technologies.

Answer (score 2):

You can bundle a lightweight server with it. My favorite application that does this is Google Refine, it is a pure web app that bundles a lightweight embedded web server (Jetty):
http://code.google.com/p/google-refine/

Comment: @johan-prinsloo Interesting. I will see how it does. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question you are talking about HTML5 offline mode.
This is what I think is the best approach:
With Wicket.Ajax.registerPreCallHandler() you can add an interceptor (a function) that will check window.offline and either let the ajax call go to the server or suppress it and execute some custom JavaScript that will save the related data in browser's DB (see localStorage, IndexedDB, web sql database). I.e. it is your job to decide what to happen when linkX is clicked and there is no internet connection. In this case you'll need also to subscribe for "ononline" event and upload the collected data when the connection is back.

Sounds like a fun project.
Good luck!

Comment: Not all browsers support HTML5 so take that into consideration as well